# How to preserving textbox value after submission

Tags: django-templates, django-views

"help me out am newbis in django"

## in Template

```
<form method="get" role="search"> 
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
<button type="submit">submit</botton>
</form>
```

after clicking on form submit ,it displays search result but text box value is null. i want to search keyword there ...
how to achieve this using java script .. ?

Answer (score 0):

1-using the manual form

just put request.GET.search in the value, nothing to change in your views

## template

```
<form method="GET">
    Search: <input type="text" name="search"
                value="{{ request.GET.search }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

2 - using forms

## What about if you use form? Well, we will use session variable here.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
   
class SearchForm (forms.Form) :
    search = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

template

```
<form method="GET">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from app_name.forms import SearchForm

def myview(request):
    if request.GET.get('search'):
        request.session['search'] = request.GET.get('search')
        #do query searching here
       
               
    form = SearchForm(initial={
        'search': request.session.get('search')
    })
    return render(request, 'search_page.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a form object, then in your view, you can do:

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        return render(request, 'searchPage.html', {'form':form,})
```